# Is there a way to increase String size in php to load 3GB content?

Tags: php, memory-limit

I am trying to load a serialized php object from a 3.14gb file to unserialize it again as an object. I have a very specific calculation purpose. That is why I am trying to do this.

I can't use file_get_contents as it truncates the content. (it gives a warning, that is how I know that).

When I try to read and append that data manually to an empty string, this time I get `Fatal error: String size overflow`.

I have 16gb ram and ssd disk and I use OS X 10.11.1 `memory_limit` is `-1`. I know that it will use swap, so I accept it to be slow. Currently I couldn't figure out a way to load this data back to php. Do you have any ideas? Is there anything that can be done at this moment?

Comment: I believe you're hitting a limit for 32 bit string lengths PHP - I believe PHP7 supports 64bit though, might be worth https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.0.0alpha2/UPGRADING (Support for strings with length >= 2^31 bytes in 64 bit builds.)

Comment: is it possible to chunk into multiple string?? so it can store more than 2GB ??

Comment: I suppose there is no standard method to fulfill your request. But you may implement `unserialize()` method that will consume stream.